# tag-it: function for select in autocomplete not working

Tags: jquery, tag-it

I am using tag-it plugin to take tag inputs from the user. The tag source for autocompletion used is through an ajax call which returns json objects using which I map values and names of tags to display to the user. The json object also contain ID for each of the tag which I don't want to show to the user but send to the server instead of the tag label/value. To do that, I thought I could use a function under "select" option generally available in autocomplete. This function would maintain an array of all the IDs selected by the user. But the select function is just not getting called when I select a tag. The code I am using is as follows:

```
   $("#myTags").tagit({
        allowSpaces: true,
        autocomplete: {
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:5555/api/Tag",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                      strSearch: request.term
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.Name, //Use rest of the data to map IDs
                                value: item.Name,
                                ID: item.ID
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 1,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                console.log(ui.item.label + "=" + ui.item.ID);
            }

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, selection didn't work when using UP / DOWN keys and ENTER. Worked jut with mouse and tab.

I've tried some key detection code as suggested in other post (if key == 13), but none worked for me.

My solution was to put focus event where I store temporarily the last object that has the focus. Then, when user hits enter key or clicks with the mouse, I check if the typed label is the same that the last on focus label. This is the same effect as if the label was 'selected':

```
// Variable used to store temporarily the focused label from
// the autocomplete list.
var focusedTag   = null;

$('#tags-list').tagit({

    fieldName: 'tags',

    autocomplete: {

        source: function (request, response) { /* Load your list... */ },

        // Stored the tag that received focus temporarily, to solve
        // enter key problem.
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            focusedTag = ui.item;
        },

        delay: 100,
        minLength: 3
    },

    afterTagAdded: function (event, ui) {

        if (focusedTag !== null &&
                focusedTag.label === ui.tagLabel) {
            // Same as if it was selected...
        }

        focusedTag   = null;

    },

    allowSpaces: true
});
```

Cheers.